# Can't sync Entity Framework model and database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, migration

I am new to Entity Framework and I'm inheriting a project that uses it. Currently I'm in a situation where everything appears to be in sync, but EF insists that they aren't. In short,

- All of my migrations appear in `[__MigrationsHistory]`, so I would assume they are all applied.
- When I try to start the WPF app backed by my model, I get the exception `The model backing the <Database> context has changed since the database was created.`
- Given this, I assume there are changes in the model that need to be migrated to the database, so I run `Add-Migration Test` to see what EF thinks needs to be added. Herein lies the problem—the migration that's added tries to add things that already exist in the database. E.g., a create table statement for a table that's already there.
- If I run `Update-Database` after adding the above migration I get the expected error, `There is already an object named 'Table' in the database.`

At this point I'm suck. I'm in a loop where everything seems to be fine, but EF thinks it isn't. How do I reconcile things?

Comment: Are you sure that the correct  connectionstring is used by EF commands?

Comment: Yeah, I triple checked that because it definitely seems like the most likely issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the command

```
Update-database -script
```

This will generate and update SQL script for you. In this script remove the part where it is creating the duplicate table. Make sure you run the whole script except this part. Your database and migration table should be up to date now.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked, I think. I'm kind of surprised because I had to comment out everything in the script except for the insert into `[__MigrationHistory]`—it literally did no updates to the schema. But everything seems to be working now. Thanks.

Comment: This is correct. Somewhere along the line you migrations and database have gotten out of sync. Your migrations table and DB schema are up to date now.